# How to fix 'EEException: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.' in GEE for python

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I tried exporting a number of images to my google drive, but my code failed to work. Instead,I received:

```
WARNING:googleapiclient.http:Invalid JSON content from response: b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",\n        "domain": "googleapis.com",\n        "metadata": {\n          "service": "earthengine.googleapis.com",\n          "method": "google.earthengine.v1alpha.EarthEngine.ExportImage"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n...
EEException: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

How do I fix this?
Here's my code:

```
import ee
import geemap as gm
import geopandas as gpd

# connect google drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/shp/Western_North/Western_North.shp'

# define a function to remove clouds from the image
def cloudRemover(input_image):
  cloudProb = input_image.select('MSK_CLDPRB')
  cloud = cloudProb.lt(5)
  scl = input_image.select('SCL')
  shadow = scl.eq(3); #3 = cloud shadow
  cirrus = scl.eq(10); #10 = cirrus
  mask = cloud.And(cirrus.neq(1)).And(shadow.neq(1))
  return input_image.updateMask(mask) \
    .copyProperties(input_image, ['system:time_start'])
    
# define a function to compute ndvi from image
def addNDVI(input_image):
  ndvi = input_image.normalizedDifference(["B8", "B4"]).rename('ndvi')  
  return input_image.addBands(ndvi)

shp = gpd.read_file(data_dir)
shp_roi = shp[shp["REGION"] == "Western Region"]
data = '/content/drive/MyDrive/shp/Western_North/WR.shp'
shp_roi.to_file(data)

# convert shapefile to earth engine object
aoi = gm.shp_to_ee(data)

# load sentinel-2 data
image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED') \
          .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20)) \
          .filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-01-01', '2022-12-10')) \
          .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi)) \
          .map(cloudRemover) \
          .map(addNDVI)
# batch export the collected images to a gdrive
for i, image_id in enumerate(image_ids):
  img = ee.Image(image.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", image_id)).first())
  task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**{
      'image': img.select('ndvi'),
      'description': 'Image Export {}'.format(i+1),
      'fileNamePrefix': image_id,
      'folder':'image_data',
      'scale': 100,
      'maxPixels': 1e10
  })
  task.start()
  print('Started Task: ', i+1)
```

Comment: Please make sure that your GEE API client library is to up to date and possibly try to regenerate your authentication token. You can find instructions for updating and authenticating here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install

Comment: Use `task.status()` to get more info about the process.

Answer (score 2):

I obtained this error due to the authentication process. First time you authenticate your GEE account you should to complete the following:

[image]

You should not check the Use **read-only scopes option**. Your problem is probably because you checked this option. You must re-authenticate the account using `ee.Authenticate()`.